# Proving the dimension of basis of given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove    or      disprove    the     following 
statement :

If       $B = {(b_1 , b_2 , b_3 , b_4 , b_5) }$    is      a       basis 
for $\mathbb{R}^5$     and     $V$  is a two-dimensional 
subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ , then  $V$  has a basis 
made of just two members of  $B$.

As it is given that dimensions of $V$ is 2, so the basis must have two elements. also, it must be a subset of $B$. But how do i connect these to prove ?

Comment: To get you on the right track, the statement is false. Try looking for some counter-examples.

Comment: Let us take standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$ and consider two dimension subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that last two coordinates are zero and sum of first three is zero. then its has a basis such that none of them belongs to standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Comment: tackle a simpler problem in fewer dimensions first; consider $(0,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ but the subspace $\{(x,y,0)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ has no such basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $$\{(1,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}$$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$.  If we take the span of any two vectors from this basis, the vectors in it all have three or more zero coordinates.  So, if we can find a two dimensional subspace containing $(1,1,1,0,0)$ say, then it's a counterexample.

---

Here's a counting proof:  There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ subsets of $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_5\}$ of size $2$.  Hence, if the statement were true, $\mathbb{R}^5$ would have only $10$ two-dimensional subspaces.  In fact, there are infinitely many two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$.